# Python list of conditions to single condition

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements, logic

I have a list of conditions such as the following:

```
mylist = [['<', 1000], ['<', 100],['<', 25],['>', 10],['>', 5]]
```

The result would be:

```
mylist = [['<', 25],['>', 10]]
```

Essentially it would take the smallest number of the '<' condition and or the largest number of the '>' condition.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) to group by the operator and then find the min/max of the second value as appropriate:

```
import itertools

mylist = [['<', 1000], ['<', 100],['<', 25],['>', 10],['>', 5]]

out = [min(g) if k == '<' else max(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=lambda l:l[0])]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['<', 25], ['>', 10]]
```

**Note**

If your list is not already sorted by operator, you should sort it prior to using `groupby` using `list.sort`:

```
mylist.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max`, after first filtering the target list with `filter`:

```
mylist = [['<', 1000], ['<', 100],['<', 25],['>', 10],['>', 5]]
result = [min(filter(lambda x:x[0] == '<', mylist)), max(filter(lambda x:x[0] == '>', mylist))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with `min`, `max` and list comprehension:

```
mylist = [['<', 1000], ['<', 100],['<', 25],['>', 10],['>', 5]]

ls=[min([i for i in mylist if i[0]=='<'],key=lambda x: x[1]),max([i for i in mylist if i[0]=='>'],key=lambda x: x[1])]

print(ls)
```

Also you can try this using `sorted`:

```
mylist = [['<', 1000], ['<', 100],['<', 25],['>', 100],['>', 5]]
ls=[sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))[0],sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))[-1]]
print(ls)
```

Both outputs:

```
[['<', 25], ['>', 10]]
```

Answer (score -1):

could do this with two quick lines like this:

```
lower = sorted([ele for ele in mylist if '>' in ele], key=lambda x:x[1])[-1]
upper = sorted([ele for ele in mylist if '<' in ele], key=lambda x:x[1])[0]

print(upper, lower)
```

output:

```
['<', 25] ['>', 10]
```

or even:

```
out = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
print(out[0], out[-1])
```

output:

```
['<', 25] ['>', 10]
```

Comment: Hey, could you explain to me what the difference is between your second solution and mine (which was published before yours). I was just asking, because it could be seen as  plagiarism.

Comment: it's a cleaner more concise version of the same core idea

Comment: It borders the plagiarism. It's almost the same solution, be concise of that.

Comment: I personally don't think it's plagiarism, mine would even run twice as fast as yours..and all the answers were posted within a couple min of eachother I actually didn't even see your code

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers) about possible duplicates answers and how to deal with it. Maybe you didn't see my code when creating the answer, but you saw, after posting your answer, that other person has answered the same thing, you should erase yours, or edit it to give a different solution, because it is plagiarism, even indirectly. BTW, if you downvoted, maybe you could give an explanation of why did you do that, please.